# Jmeter POST parameter with request email address - (@ symbol treated as %40)

Tags: java, https, jmeter, http-post

http request - post - send parameters with the following `userpassword,username,loginbtn,_requestToken`

username is email address please refer the below screen

[image]

checking with result tree @ symbol treated as `%40`

refer the below screen

[image]

Question:
it's not logged into the application while running,

same time when i click the `Body Data` in my http request its shows like "`cannot convert parameters to Body data, because one of the parameters has a name`"

Please advice

Comment: uncheck encode parameters

Comment: @Rohit Thanks for the replay, i already unchecked and tried(encode) getting same result,adc%40abc.com

Answer (score 0):

Special sybmol is encoded by jmeter and hence it is like that. It is the base 64 encode and %40 represents @. I think your problem is not this and lie somewhere else.

As per your snapshot, it seems like your "Request verification token" is not passing through properly. Hence, this request is failing.

> Reserved characters:URLs use some characters for special use in
>   defining their syntax. When these characters are not used in their
>   special role inside a URL, they need to be encoded, example : '$',
>   '&', '+', ',' , '/', ':', ';', '=', '?', '@'

Reference:-https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

About your second point, You can use either use body data or send parameters with the request and not both at the same time.

Also, check "[authorization manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)" for authentication and use it with [cookie manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager).

Basic authentication  blogs;-https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication

Hope it helps.